# Possibility to pass command line arguments via URL to RAP-Application

Tags: eclipse-rap

Is there a possibility to pass command line arguments via URL to RAP-Application? I'm using RAP 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround. First I read the request parameters:

```
RWT.getRequest().getParameterMap();
```

Second I read the command line args to get the defaults which are entered in the web.xml:

```
Platform.getCommandLineArgs();
```

Finally I merge them with the http parameters as leading one.